# Changing the URL formatting in phpBB

Tags: url, phpbb

Some forums show links that look like static files. For example this one:
http://romaniaraw.freeforums.org/principii-f33.html

however, it also works like this:
http://romaniaraw.freeforums.org/viewforum.php?f=33

How can I tell to phpbb to change the URL formatting from one way to another? (for the moment, the forum is set to show the links in the first manner)

Do those two types of URL formatting have names, by the way?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^principii-f([0-9]+).html  /viewforum.php?f=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: So I have to do that for every single forum and thread? Is there a way for the regular forum users to change the URL formatting in options?

Comment: I am not sure that phpbb provide url formatting option.

Comment: It must have such an option - look at this forum - https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewforum.php?f=556 - the URL's are formatted to contain "viewforum.php" and "viewtopic.php"